# Efficiency of 3 in line boosters of a shuttle?

Tags: space-shuttle, fuel, physics, booster

What is the most efficient scenario for a total of 700 Newtons of thrust on three lined up boosters? If the air pressure for the payload booster isn't the same, can they make an efficient air turbulence pattern which generates more lift?

- 233, 233, 233
- 200, 300, 200
- 266, 166, 266

Comment: 700 N of what? Thrust? Aerodynamic forces?

Comment: yes of thrust .

Comment: and what do you mean by "If the air pressure for the payload booster isn't the same"  - the same as on the side boosters? Are you thinking of the Falcon Heavy, where the center core has a larger cross-section?